# How to install PHP XMLWriter on FreeBSD

Tags: php, freebsd, xmlwriter

I found a good library called [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) on github and started to use it in my application. All works ok on localhost, but when I charged files on my Server, running FreeBSD system,  PHP throws the following error:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'XMLWriter' not found in 
.../PHPOffice/PHPExcel/Shared/XMLWriter.php on line 44"
while reading response header from upstream
```

Please, can someone help me to enable [XMLWriter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) library?
Thank You in advance!

Comment: Is it a server you have full control on? How do you install other software packages?

Comment: Yes, I have full control on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it! For XMLWriter I used:

```
portinstall php5-xmlwriter
```

for XMLReader:

```
portinstall php5-xmlreader
```

Comment: This is what I meant with "How do you install other software packages?" (which you ignored). However, the answer you've accepted suggest to install the third-party PEAR distribution (thus skipping the builtin library). How did you really fix the issue?

Comment: I really fixed the issue like I've wrote in [comment to @Johnson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376767/how-to-install-php-xmlwriter-on-freebsd#comment41412748_26376890)

Comment: I accepted his answer becauese it led me to find solution. Ok if I were a bit more attentive and wouldn't ignore your second question maybe I would fix it faster.